# 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector in ExpDes package

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to do an analysis using `ExpDes` package, however, the function doesn't run because an error appears:

`Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [3]`

```
    library(ExpDes)

temperature <- c(20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40,40,40,40)
    chemicals <- c(0,10,20,30,0,10,20,30,0,10,20,30)
    contaminant_A <- c(9,22,25,28,35,50,57,78,86,94,97,100)
    contaminant_B <- c(0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 5,11,11,13,18,18,21)
    contaminant_C <- c(68,57,53,50,44,38,36,34,31,29,25,24)
    contaminant_D <- c(39,68,35,32,53,69,69,60,35,30,43,36)

    DF <- data.frame(temperature,
                 chemicals,
                 contaminant_A,
                 contaminant_B,
                 contaminant_C,
                 contaminant_D)

    attach(DF)
    fat2.crd(temperature, chemicals, contaminant_A, quali = c(FALSE, FALSE), mcomp = "tukey",
         fac.names = c("Temperature","Chemicals"), sigT = 0.05, sigF = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type `fat2.crd` in the console you can see the source code of the function. In that they apply `aov` to factor and response variables passed. Before doing that they convert the factor variables to `factor` class and then take `summary` of it and change the column names. To summarise, what they are trying to do is

```
a1 <- summary(aov(DF$contaminant_A~factor(DF$temperature) * factor(DF$chemicals)))
a1

#                                            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#factor(DF$temperature)                       2  10749    5375
#factor(DF$chemicals)                         3    998     333
#factor(DF$temperature):factor(DF$chemicals)  6    279      47
```

and then do

```
colnames(a1[[1]]) <- c("DF", "SS", "MS", "Fc", "Pr>Fc")
```

which gives

> Error in names(x) <- value : 
>     'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [3]

since there are only 3 columns and the function is passing 5 names to rename.

We can write our own version of the function, where we don't convert the class of the factor variables passed and use them as it is

```
a1 <- summary(aov(DF$contaminant_A~DF$temperature * DF$chemicals))
a1
#                            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#DF$temperature               1  10731   10731  267.04 1.98e-07 ***
#DF$chemicals                 1    968     968   24.09  0.00118 ** 
#DF$temperature:DF$chemicals  1      6       6    0.14  0.71803    
#Residuals                    8    321      40                     
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1ctor`
```

and then change the column names

```
colnames(a1[[1]]) <- c("DF", "SS", "MS", "Fc", "Pr>Fc")
```

which runs without error but I am not sure what implications it might have in the analysis.

Comment: If you run the example on the page 24 of the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ExpDes/ExpDes.pdf), there is no need to transform anything. Could you help me?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. yes, that's what I compared to when writing the answer. I don't understand the statistics behind it but compare the results of `a1 <- summary(aov(DF$contaminant_A~factor(DF$temperature) * factor(DF$chemicals)))` and `a2 <- summary(aov(ex4$zn~factor(ex4$revol) * factor(ex4$esterco)))` you see two columns less in `a1` hence the error. That is the main difference between the two examples.